# Download mysql Table with php nusoap

Tags: php, mysql, nusoap

I want to export/download a table from a mysql database to a txt or csv file like the way you can in phpmyadmin. The table can be anywhere from 100 - 90k entries and the mysql query will take place on a php page.

Comment: mysqldump http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use INTO OUTFILE ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html